# Cache Share Link - Automatic solution to clear cache

Tags: facebook, caching

I have several webpages with facebook metatags. The problem is, that Facebook is starting recognize them only after I've used object's [Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). How can I force Facebook to automatically resolve all my meta-tags?

Facebook should upgrade to the updated link when i post a link.
Facebook dont do this Job, it should not do?

What is the solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `curl` method?

```
curl -v https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=YOUR_URL_HERE&format=json
```

If that works you could set up an automatic script/cron job to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work! just needed the -L option as facebook seems to be redirecting all over the place.